# Communication between two iframes from the same domain with postMessage

Tags: html, iframe, same-origin-policy, postmessage

I have two iframes from the same domain, which are hosted in document from another domain. The problem is these iframes cannot communicate with each other through postMessage. I cant even access the DOM of iframe1 from iframe2 even though they belong to same domain. Is there any solution ????

I used following options to refer the required iframe.

```
parent.frame[x]
```

I tried following lines to access DOM of iframes

```
parent.frame[x].contentWindow returns null,

parent.frame[x].document.getElementsByTagName("body") returns null
```

---

Update:

I guess my question is not clear enough. There is no problem with postMessage api, the actual problem is browser creates a custom frameset around the iframe document, in my case!

So `parent.frame[x]` won't point to the iframe window, instead it points to the custom frameset inside the iframe window.

Following question explains the problem well.

[Prevent browser from loading a custom frameset in an iframe's document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176590/prevent-browser-from-loading-a-custom-frameset-in-an-iframes-document)

Answer (score 5):

If you want cross-window same-domain communication, you can set it up via `localStorage`. When you add an item to `localStorage`, you get window `"storage"` event in all other windows / iframes / tabs of the same domain.

So, you basically `localStorage.setItem('name', 'value')` in one iframe while you listen to `window.addEventListener('storage', (event) => {/* handle message */})` and you get the message.

Comment: Sir, your solution there, 4 years later, just got me out of despair. This is brilliant, and works like a charm :)

Comment: Aye this solution has saved me a lot of bother, cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the following description of the [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) function and how it could be used. So in frame1 you call the `postMessage` method and in frame2 you subscribe for notifications. Obviously the browser you are using must support this API.

There's also a very nice [jQuery plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/) which wraps this API and simplifies its usage. It also works in browsers that do not support the `postMessage` method by using the hash portion of the url.

Comment: @sawren, yes they can, even if they are on different domains.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, no, of course not. OP asked how can two child iframes communicate with each other. With just postMessage, they cannot, because they don't have access to the parent's DOM AND they don't see each other AND the parent can't pass a reference to an iframe into another iframe.

I would suggest either setting up an RPC bettween two iframes in the parent (if those iframes are parts of an SDK, which you integrate into the parent). Or just use localStorage and window storage event (the simplest solution).